# How do I ignore lines that are commented out when parsing?

Tags: rebol, rebol3

I have a PHP array that I'm parsing to get email addresses. Sometimes I'll want to comment an entry so I can use a different value for testing.

Here's an example of the array:

```
array('system.email' => array(
    'to' => array(
        'contactus' => 'contactus@example.com',
        'newregistration' => 'newreg@example.com', 
        'requestaccess' => 'requestaccess@example.com',
//            'workflow' => 'workflow@example.com'
        'workflow' => 'test_workflow@example.com'
    )  
));
```

Here's my PARSE rule:

```
parse read %config.php [
    thru "'system.email'" [
        thru "'to'" [thru "'workflow'" [thru "'" copy recipient-email to "'^/"]]
    ] to end
]
```

When I run that, the value of `recipient-email` is "workflow@example.com".  How can I write my rule such that it ignores the line that begins with `//`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A rule for eating up a comment line would look something like this:

```
spacer: charset reduce [tab cr newline #" "]
spaces: [some spacer]
any-spaces: [any spacer]

[any-spaces "//" thru newline]
```

You may judge how you want to do that with your current rule.  Here's a somewhat messy way to deal with only comments in the array.

```
text: {array('system.email' => array(                                                      
    'to' => array(                                                                  
        'contactus' => 'contactus@example.com',                                     
        'newregistration' => 'newreg@example.com',                                  
        'requestaccess' => 'requestaccess@example.com',                             
//            'workflow' => 'workflow@example.com'                                  
        'workflow' => 'test_workflow@example.com'                                   
    )                                                                               
));}

list: []

spacer: charset reduce [tab cr newline #" "]
any-spaces: [any spacer]

comment-rule: [any-spaces "//" thru newline]

email-rule: [
    thru "'"
    copy name to "'" skip
    thru "'" 
    copy email to "'"
    thru newline
]

system-emails: [
    thru "'system.email'" [  
        thru "to' => array(" 
        some [
            comment-rule |
            email-rule (append list reduce [name email])
        ]    
    ] to end
]

parse text system-emails
print list
```

This will result in a block of the names and emails from the array.

Maybe a more holistic approach could process the source and remove all comments before parsing.  This is a function I have used in the past:

```
decomment: func [str [string!] /local new-str com comment-removing-rule] [

    new-str: copy ""

    com: [
        "//"
        thru newline
    ]
    comment-removing-rule: [
        some [
            com |
            copy char skip (append new-str char)
        ]
    ]

    parse str comment-removing-rule
    return new-str
]
```

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive answer! I think I like the decomment option better.

Comment: It is a better option.  I don't know PHP (Thank goodness!) but you can add whatever other kinds of comments as options to the comment rule to remove others (ie `"/*" thru "*/"`).